# PHP - How to insert while loop checkbox and save to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, checkbox

The while loop checkbox name is checkextra[] and value is price echo using php `<?php echo $show_extra['price']; ?>`

Now the following code only workable for the price - it save perfectly with the checkbox i checked. But the `$show_extra['item_name']` are not saving accordingly. In DB all the item_name are giving me the last while loop item , it not same like the price save perfectly.

The code bellow i have modify a lot of time but the output of `item_name`  still same

```
<div class="adjust">
<center><form class="greatForm" method="post" action="#">
<?php
$read_extra = mysql_query("select * from extra_item where theme_name = '$title'");

while($show_extra = mysql_fetch_array($read_extra))
{
    $getextraname = $show_extra['item_name'];

?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkextra[]" id="<?php echo       $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" value="<?php echo $show_extra['price']; ?>"/>
    <label for="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" >
    <img style="height:150px;width:150px;" src="<?php echo 'themeinfo/extra/'.$show_extra['item_img']; ?>"/><?php echo $show_extra['item_name']; ?>  </label>

<?php
}
 ?>
<center><br><br><input type="submit" class="button" style="width:10%;" value="SAVE"  name="choose_extra"></center></br>
</form></center>
<?php


    if(isset($_POST['choose_extra']))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['checkextra'])) {
    foreach($_POST['checkextra'] as $getextraprice) {
    $takeextra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO selectextra(user,title,extraitem,price) 
                            VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."',
                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($getextraname)."',
                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($getextraprice)."')") or die(mysql_error());

        }
        if($takeextra)
            {
                echo "<center>Extra item order SAVE.</center>";
            }
            else{
                echo "failed";
            }
    }
}

?>

</div>
```

DB item_name all get the same

```
-- Table structure for table `extra_item`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `extra_item` (
`theme_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`item_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`item_label` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`price` int(10) NOT NULL,
`item_img` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--

-- Table structure for table `selectextra`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `selectextra` (
`user` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`extraitem` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`price` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
```

- - Dumping data for table `selectextra`
   --

```
INSERT INTO `selectextra` (`user`, `title`, `extraitem`, `price`) VALUES
('qweqwe', 'test', 'red balloon4', 10),
('qweqwe', 'test', 'red balloon4', 10),
('qweqwe', 'test', 'red balloon4', 1),
('qweqwe', 'test', 'red balloon4', 1),
('qweqwe', 'test', 'red balloon4', 1),
('qweqwe', 'test', 'red balloon4', 2),
```

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated, do some research into mysqli_query and you should receive a more detailed error after implementing.

Comment: I think that in your queries you need to take `$title` out of the single quotes because the value in that variable won't be picked up. So it should read: `"select * from theme where title = '" . $title . "'`

Comment: @CoderDojo but im using phpmyadmin

Comment: @user1849060 hi , but the problem is not there. And that one also not a checkbox and while loop, i asking for insert problem

Comment: Your insert is not in a loop. It could only do one insert and doesn't seem to take any notice of which checkboxes are checked.

Comment: @Kickstart question said while loop checkbox not while loop insert

Comment: @user3652484 Using PHPMyAdmin has no bearing on what connector you use to access your database. As CoderDojo said **MySql_*** is depreciated in PHP and should not be used to connect to a MySQL database. You should use *MySQLi* or *PDO* to connect to your database.

Comment: You are not retrieving the values from the checkboxes. You do use 2 session variables which will store the initial price and item name of the last row retrieved from the table (irrespective of whether checked or not). If you echo out the insert SQL and try it manually in phpmyadmin what do you get? Change `echo "failed";` to `echo "failed ".mysql_error();` to see the error message from the query in the script.

Comment: @Styphon i only understand on mysql i never learn mysqli before .. please help my question

Comment: @user3652484 Mysqli is very similar to mysql, it doesn't take much to learn the differences. You should take the time to learn. You won't be able to use mysql for much longer.

Comment: @user1849060 is very urgent and i have no more time ... only left this question ... please help

Comment: Without your table definitions / data / etc there is not much we can suggest. The SQL looks OK (even if the logic is strange), but there could be many other problem (eg, if the table selectextra has another column which is set to NOT NULL and with no default). Put  or die(mysql_error()) on the end of your mysql query lines (eg `$takeextra = mysql_query("insert into selectextra(user,title,extraitem,price) values('$username','$title','$getextraname,'$getextraprice')") or die(mysql_error());` ) and see what is output as the error

Answer (score 0):

Changed to mysqli, and with some messages to put out debugging info, try this (set up the database connection fields to suit your db):-

```
<div class="adjust">
<?php

$link = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "databasename");

if ($link->connect_errno) 
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $link->connect_error);
    exit();
}

?>
<center><form class="greatForm" method="post" action="#">
<?php

$sql = "SELECT price, item_name, item_label, item_img FROM extra_item WHERE theme_name = '$title'";

if ( ($read_extra = $link->query($sql)===false )
{
  echo "Invalid query: ".$link->error."\r\n $sql\r\n";
  exit();
}

while($show_extra = $read_extra->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $_SESSION['getextraprice'] = $show_extra['price'];
    $_SESSION['getextraname'] = $show_extra['item_name'];
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $show_extra['price']; ?>" id="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" value="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>"/>
    <label for="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" >
    <img style="height:150px;width:150px;" src="<?php echo 'themeinfo/extra/'.$show_extra['item_img']; ?>"/><?php echo $show_extra['item_name']; ?></label>

<?php
}
 ?>
<center><br><br><input type="submit" class="button" style="width:10%;" value="SAVE" name="choose_extra"></center></br>
</form></center>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['choose_extra']))
    {
        $getextraprice = $_SESSION['getextraprice'];
        $getextraname = $_SESSION['getextraname'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO selectextra(user,title,extraitem,price) VALUES('$username','$title','$getextraname,'$getextraprice')";
        if ( ($insert = $link->query($sql)===false )
        {
          echo "failed: ".$link->error."\r\n $sql\r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Order SAVE.";
        }
    }
?>

</div>

</div>
```

EDIT - if you really want to use mysql_* calls then try this, which will at least let you know what the errors are:-

```
<div class="adjust">
<center><form class="greatForm" method="post" action="#">
<?php
$read_extra = mysql_query("SELECT price, item_name, item_label, item_img FROM extra_item where theme_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."'") or die(mysql_error());

while($show_extra = mysql_fetch_array($read_extra))
{
    $_SESSION['getextraprice'] = $show_extra['price'];
    $_SESSION['getextraname'] = $show_extra['item_name'];
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $show_extra['price']; ?>" id="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" value="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>"/>
    <label for="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" >
    <img style="height:150px;width:150px;" src="<?php echo 'themeinfo/extra/'.$show_extra['item_img']; ?>"/><?php echo $show_extra['item_name']; ?></label>

<?php
}
 ?>
<center><br><br><input type="submit" class="button" style="width:10%;" value="SAVE" name="choose_extra"></center></br>
</form></center>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['choose_extra']))
    {
        $getextraprice = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['getextraprice']);
        $getextraname = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['getextraname']);
        $takeextra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO selectextra(user,title,extraitem,price) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','$getextraname,'$getextraprice')") or die(mysql_error());

        if($takeextra)
        {
            echo "Order SAVE.";
        }
        else{
            echo "failed";
        }
    }
?>

</div>

</div>
```

If you want to get the checkboxes that have been ticked then something like this would do it:-

```
<div class="adjust">
<center><form class="greatForm" method="post" action="#">
<?php
$read_extra = mysql_query("SELECT price, item_name, item_label, item_img FROM extra_item where theme_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."'") or die(mysql_error());

while($show_extra = mysql_fetch_array($read_extra))
{
    $_SESSION['getextraprice'] = $show_extra['price'];
    $_SESSION['getextraname'] = $show_extra['item_name'];
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $show_extra['price']; ?>" id="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" value="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>"/>
    <label for="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" >
    <img style="height:150px;width:150px;" src="<?php echo 'themeinfo/extra/'.$show_extra['item_img']; ?>"/><?php echo $show_extra['item_name']; ?></label>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['choose_extra']) and array_key_exists($show_extra['price'], $_POST) and $_POST[$show_extra['price']] != '')
    {
        $takeextra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO selectextra(user, title, extraitem, price) 
                                VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($show_extra['item_name'])."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$show_extra['price']])."')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
 ?>
<center><br><br><input type="submit" class="button" style="width:10%;" value="SAVE" name="choose_extra"></center></br>
</form></center>
</div>
</div>
```

Note this is very much a guess as it seems very strange to have fields on which the field name is a numeric price.

EDIT - further update based on guesses:-

```
<div class="adjust">
<center><form class="greatForm" method="post" action="#">
<?php
$read_extra = mysql_query("select id, item_label, price, item_name, item_img from extra_item where theme_name = '$title'");

while($show_extra = mysql_fetch_array($read_extra))
{
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkextra[".$show_extra['id']."]' id='".$show_extra['item_label']."' value='".$show_extra['price']."'/>";
    echo "<label for='".$show_extra['item_label']."' >";
    echo "<img style='height:150px;width:150px;' src='themeinfo/extra/'".$show_extra['item_img']."'/>".$show_extra['item_name']."</label>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name[".$show_extra['id']."]' value='".$show_extra['item_name']."'/>";
}

echo "<center><br><br><input type='submit' class='button' style='width:10%;' value='SAVE'  name='choose_extra'></center></br>";
echo "</form></center>";

if(isset($_POST['choose_extra']))
{
    foreach($_POST['checkextra'] as $getextraprice_id=>$getextraprice) 
    {
        $takeextra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO selectextra(user,title,extraitem,price) 
                                VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_name'][$getextraprice_id])."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($getextraprice)."')") or die(mysql_error());

    }
    if($takeextra)
    {
        echo "<center>Extra item order SAVE.</center>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed";
    }
}

?>

</div>
```

Put out the checkbox with a value of the price, and a hidden field containing the item_name. Both as arrays. The index of these arrays should match. When you process the form you loop through the checkboxes you get the index of each checkbox array item and use that as the index to access the item_name field.

EDIT again. Used a sequence number to force the index of the arrays of form elements (probably should be necessary, but I prefer to force things) rather than using a field from the table.

```
<div class="adjust">
<center><form class="greatForm" method="post" action="#">
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test', $conn);
$title = 'fred';
$username = 'jo';

$read_extra = mysql_query("SELECT item_label, price, item_name, item_img FROM extra_item WHERE theme_name = '$title'");

$row_cnt = 0;
while($show_extra = mysql_fetch_array($read_extra))
{
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkextra[$row_cnt]' id='".$show_extra['item_label']."' value='".$show_extra['price']."'/>";
    echo "<label for='".$show_extra['item_label']."' >";
    echo "<img style='height:150px;width:150px;' src='themeinfo/extra/'".$show_extra['item_img']."'/>".$show_extra['item_name']."</label>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='item_name[$row_cnt]' value='".$show_extra['item_name']."'/>";
    $row_cnt++;
}

echo "<center><br><br><input type='submit' class='button' style='width:10%;' value='SAVE'  name='choose_extra'></center></br>";
echo "</form></center>";

if(isset($_POST['choose_extra']))
{
    foreach($_POST['checkextra'] as $getextraprice_id=>$getextraprice) 
    {
        $takeextra = mysql_query("INSERT INTO selectextra(user,title,extraitem,price) 
                                VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_name'][$getextraprice_id])."',
                                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($getextraprice)."')") or die(mysql_error());

    }
    if($takeextra)
    {
        echo "<center>Extra item order SAVE.</center>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed";
    }
}

?>

</div>
```

Comment: i dont understand mysqli

Comment: It is virtually the same sql normal mysql_* calls that you are already using. But the main thing to do is to add the debugging so we have some idea of what the error is that your code is failing with

Comment: but my problem is how to insert checkbox name and value to database. The checkbox is generate by while loop.

Comment: And you say that it comes out with the message saying 'failed'. But that doesn't say WHY it failed (hence the extra code to put out the mysql error messages). Once output you do not know what the checkbox names are to read the values in, and the easiest way to process them would be in a loop, but you have commented that "question said while loop checkbox not while loop insert". If you want to process the checkboxes already checked then the best place to do that would be in the loop that outputs the checkboxes, as then you know the names of the fields output.

Comment: actually the failed is echo, if query not insert echo failed. I have updated my question a bit. I put the checkbox name to `name="checkextra[]"` and now it give me this **Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\**

Comment: i try your recent code it save to db but it save last generate checkbox data . for instance , i have four checkbox, i check first one and submit to database, in database the data not showing the first checkbox data it shows fourth one .

Comment: I just tried it and it seems to work for me (minor bug fixed with it). But it is (as with your original script) using the price as a label. Are any of the prices in your db the same?

Comment: hi, now i have modify entire question and some coding , the price is now saving correctly ... but the item_name still the same

Comment: That is because you are using $_SESSION['getextraname'], and you set that to the item_name for each row, over writing the previous rows value each time.

Comment: any idea to solve it ? if not using `$_SESSION['getextraname']` to pass the item_name then how to pass item_name to the insert query ?

Comment: are you still there ? how can i save the correct item_name like price

Comment: Back now. You need to save the fields in a way that they can be matched up when the form is returned. You can use hidden fields to store some of those details, or have the form names as arrays (specifying a unique id as the subscript to the array), then match that back up in your code when you read the database again. But a table key should be unique and it would seem very unlikely that a price would be unique (ie, if you had an item in a supermarket would you update the name of that item based on the price being 9.99 , when thousands of other items would have the same price and be updated).

Comment: sry i really dont understand ... im very new in php ... can u please help me to modify the code so it can also save the item_name . Now the price are store accordingly , but item_name still get the last of the loop

Comment: Probably better to take a step back. Can you update your original question with the declares of the 2 tables and some sample rows, and a description of what you want to put out and what you want to update, plus how any record to be updated can be uniquely identified.

Comment: i modified the question hope u understand . just left the item_name save it wrongly

Comment: I have added an extra suggestion, but it is still based on a guess (using an id column from the extra_item table) as you haven't given any table declares.

Comment: Please post the table declares. It is just about impossible to come up with a solution and test it without those! What is the problem you are getting now.

Comment: i want the `show_extra['item_name']` if i put  `$_POST['checkextra'][$getextraprice_id]` it get the checkbox value again not item_name

Comment: what is table declares?

Comment: can i put 2 in foreach so it also take the correct item_name?
`foreach($_POST['checkextra'] as $getextraprice=>$_POST[$show_extra['item_name']] as $getextraname)`

Comment: The tables declares = the declarations of the tables giving their layout. If you are using phpmyadmin you can get this from the export tab. I had a mistake in my code and now fixed. You can't use the foreach you described. The code mine uses loops around the $_POST['checkextra'] array, and puts the index of the array item into $getextraprice_id. It can then use this index to get the value of the matching $_POST['item_name']

Comment: Can you add the extra_item table as well please.

Comment: Added another suggestion.

Comment: but my db no have id in my table is only theme_name ... u see my table in question

Comment: Just remove it from the select (the one I knocked up on my machine does have an id field). It isn't used in the code.

Comment: hi ~ thanks you so much for helping me you such a nice person ~ and i finally found out the solution ~ the answers i has been posted . Thanks a lot ~ =)

Answer (score 0):

First have to put `$_SESSION['itemname'] = array();` on top of the html

```
<div class="adjust">
<center><form class="greatForm" method="post" action="#">
<?php
$read_extra = mysql_query("select * from extra_item where theme_name = '$title'");
$a = 1;
while($show_extra = mysql_fetch_array($read_extra))
{
    $_SESSION['getextraname'] = $show_extra['item_name'];

?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkextra<?php echo $a?>" id="<?php echo   $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" value="<?php echo $show_extra['price']; ?>"/>
    <label for="<?php echo $show_extra['item_label']; ?>" >
    <img style="height:150px;width:150px;" src="<?php echo 'themeinfo/extra/'.$show_extra['item_img']; ?>"/><?php echo $show_extra['item_name']; ?></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="getextraname<?php echo $a?>" value="<?php echo   $show_extra['item_name']; ?>"/>

<?php
$a = $a+1;
}
 ?>
 <center><br><br><input type="submit" class="button" style="width:10%;" value="SAVE" name="choose_extra"></center></br>
</form></center>
<?php


    if(isset($_POST['choose_extra']))
 {


    $number = mysql_query("select COUNT(*) as num from extra_item where  theme_name = '$title'");
    $number_data = mysql_fetch_array($number);

    for($x=1;$x<=$number_data['num'];$x++)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['checkextra'.$x]))
        {
            array_push($_SESSION['itemname'],$_POST['getextraname'.$x]);
        }

    }


    foreach($_SESSION['itemname'] as $keyname)
    {
        $redname = mysql_query("select * from extra_item where theme_name = '$title' and item_name='$keyname'");
        $takename = mysql_fetch_array($redname);
        $getextraname = $takename['item_name'];
        $getextraprice = $takename['price'];

        $saveallextra = mysql_query("insert into selectextra(user,title,extraitem,price) values('$username','$title','$getextraname',$getextraprice)");

        if($saveallextra)
            {
                echo "<center>Extra item order SAVE.</center>";
            }
            else{
                echo "Failed";
            }

    }

}

?>

</div>
```